# How can dismiss all modal dialog in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

In old version of angular bootstrap i used to use

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal

```
var myApp = angular.module('app', []).run(function($rootScope, $modalStack) {
      $modalStack. dismissAll();
    });
```

I could not find what it is called in latest version

Comment: try $modalStack.dismissAll(reason);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace $modalStack with $uibModalStack

i.e.    `$uibModalStack.dismissAll()`

Comment: checked whole page could find reference to uibModalStack on that page

Comment: dismiss method will reject your promise but close method will resolve your promise. Choose wisely

Answer (score 0):

You need to just do, it's very simple if you googled :

```
$modalInstance.dismiss('cancel'); // from your controller 

$modalStack.dismissAll(reason); // for your current position.
```